# Trying to make a function that uses inputs that are lists - quadratic formula

Tags: python, list

trying to have an input that has multiple inputs - so i can solve multiple equations at once

I realise that there is probs a better quad function, but want to use mine jsut with multiple inputs

```
a= [1,2,3,4]
b=[2,4,6,8]
c=[3,6,9,12]

def quad_func(a,b,c):
    x1_values = []
    x2_values = []
    for x,y,z in a,b,c:
        x1_values.append((-y+(y**2 - 4*x*z)**0.5)/(2*x))
        x2_values.append((-y-(y**2 - 4*x*z)**0.5)/(2*x))
    return x1_values,x2_values #dont forget return
quad_func(a,b,c)
```

Cheers

Comment: Try `for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c):` as for-loop.

Comment: You could also use a for loop, a comprehension, or `map` to apply the single-input version of `quad_func`

Comment: @MichaelButscher  - i have done that but i just get the same numbers added
edit - nope you were correct and it worked perfectly thank you